# When using Apple's unified logging os_log, is there a need to use DispatchQueue.async?

Tags: swift, ios10

When using Apple's unified logging API os_log, is there a need to use DispatchQueue.async or internally it will handle executing things in the background and also queueing of messages?

Comment: You don't have to use any synchronization while using os_log API. iOS is doing all the work itself.

Answer (score 2):

**You should not.**

Apple suggested that the unified logging system already handles that for you. Quotes from [Session 721 - Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721) from WWDC 2016:

> Another thing we do that's very, very important is we defer a lot of work. As anything that we can do at the point at which you display the information instead of the point at which we collect it we try to defer to that point. That's one of the key ways that we avoid observer effect.

No where within the talk did they mention you should log from a background thread or queue. Under Best Practices:

> Avoid creating wrapper functions for `os_log*` APIs

(I take this to mean avoid creating wrappers that call `os_log` on a DispatchQueue)

> Avoid logging in tight code loops

(Unified Logging is designed to be light-weight but don't stress it to the extreme)